# xPath vs DOM API, which one has a better performance

Tags: .net, xml, dom, xpath

Well, Say I am working on a project that is gonna have lots of people online simultaneously and I need to provide them with data coming from some XML files. What would be the best way to do that when it comes to performance issues? Is there any real differences between `xPath` or `DOM` or I shouldn't care and just go ahead and use the one I like most?

Additionally, what is the problem using RegEx to parse a xml or xhtml file?

Comment: you cannot "like" something that you don't know. Start learning XML and XPath and you won't be sorry. :) I would even recommend ... gasp ... XSLT to you. :)

Comment: Actually I already know very well how to use both xPath and DOM and I don't know why did you assume that I don't, but thanks.

Comment: Asking two questions in one post is a bad idea. Please ask the regex question separately (except that it's probably been well answered before)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're interested in performance, then there may be tree models that perform much faster than DOM (for example, if you're in the Java world, XOM) and that also offer much better usability.

XPath is a high-level language, DOM APIs are much lower level. The main difference is therefore programmer productivity, ease of maintenance, etc. As to performance, a high-level language will usually be slower than a top-class programmer writing super-optimized code with a lower-level interface, but faster than an average programmer writing average code against a deadline.

Comment: +1 Very good answer enlightening misunderstood concepts: tree models (DOM vs XOM, etc.) and high-level (XPath) vs. low-level (DOM methods) language.

Answer (score 1):

Use whichever you want, the performance difference is likely negligible.  As to your last question, please see this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732454